# Windows 10 warn before launching urls

Tags: windows-10, browser, url, hyperlink, protocol

Basically I'm trying to block any applications to randomly being able to open urls with my default browser.

I've looked up windows default apps by protocol in control panel, but I wish there was an option where it would warn me before opening letting the app open a url.

Best answer for me would be a way to tell windows, hey prompt me before openning my browser! unless its opened by me.

I do have some programming skills, I'm not afraid of coding if step should include any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [Browser Chooser](https://www.browserchooser2.com/). It will ask you about a desired browser before opening a URL and allow to cancel the launch.

[image]